# MD5 Hashing returning different output than expected

Tags: java, jdbc, md5

I'm connecting lamp using JDBC and I have the word *LondonWeight* as a password hashed using MD5 on a MySQL database. I then need to check an inputted password against the collection, i.e *LondonWeight* to check to see if they match. However the hashing in my Java code returns a different output for the word.

MySQL hash:
    1274d1c52d7a5a9125bd64f1f9a26dce

Java hash:
    132310771724320562704545645352563257040366

Here's my hash code:

```
private String hashPass(String pass) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); 
    mdEnc.update(pass.getBytes(), 0, pass.length());
    String md5 = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest()).toString(8); // Encrypted 
    return md5;
}
```

It definitely hashes the String entered in the text box as I have it printed to the terminal so I can check. Any idea why it gives a different output? I understand there a different ways to hash the bytes or something?

Answer (score 7):

You're currently converting the hash into octal in Java, whereas the MySQL version is in hex.

That's the first problem, but also:

- Your MySQL hash appears to be *33* characters, which is too much data for an MD5 hash in hex. There's something odd going on there.
- I wouldn't use `BigInteger` to convert a byte array into hex anyway; that's not what it's there for. Use Apache Commons Codec or something *designed* for hex conversion. For example, that way you'll get appropriate leading zeroes which `BigInteger` may suppress
- Your current code assumes a single byte per character
- Your current code assumes that the default character encoding is appropriate; I would suggest *always* specifying an encoding in `String.getBytes`
- Using MD5 for password hashing is weak; update to a more appropriate hash if you possibly can

Comment: Any link to a tutorial or guide to do this? I'm relatively new to coding the hashing myself so I wouldn't know where to start! This was from a solution to someone else's question. And I'm only using MD5 as it's only for a Uni project so it doesn't need to be uber secure, just demonstrate some form of password protection.

Comment: @AdamShort: The trouble is that if you use something insecure now, someone else is likely to end up taking that code further etc... Anyway, which bit of advice are you stuck on? (I have no idea why you'd have a 33 character value in MySQL, for example.)

Comment: I doubt it! But the word I'm trying to hash is only 12? Would that still make it 33?

Comment: @AdamShort: An MD5 hash is always 128 bits, which leads to 32 hex characters (4 bits each).